# Difference in meaning between "good of" and "good for" and "good to"?

Tags: meaning

What is the exact difference in meaning between "It's good of you to say that" and "It's good for you to say that" and "It's good to you to say that"?

Does "It's good of you to say that" mean "If you say that, it is good" ?

Does "It's good for you to say that" mean "If you say that, it is good not for me but for you" ?

Does "It's good to you to say that" mean " If you say that, you will have good thing" ?

Comment: I tend to agree with your interpretation of the first two sentences, but the last one doesn't sound natural to me at all. I'm not sure what it would mean.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

**good of you to...**
Your actions in a particular situation were appropriate, and maybe exceeded what could reasonably be expected of you.

> It was good of you to take Geoff home last night: he was so drunk that I was worried about him!

**good for you to...**
Your actions are/will be beneficial to you.

> It's good for you to get some healthy exercise every day

It is often used in a conditional form:

> It would be good for you to get some healthy exercise every day

**good to you to...** 
As this [NGRAM](https://books.google.com/ngrams/graph?content=good%20of%20you%20to%2C%20good%20for%20you%20to%2C%20good%20to%20you%20to&year_start=1800&year_end=2000&corpus=15&smoothing=3&share=&direct_url=t1%3B%2Cgood%20of%20you%20to%3B%2Cc0%3B.t1%3B%2Cgood%20for%20you%20to%3B%2Cc0%3B.t1%3B%2Cgood%20to%20you%20to%3B%2Cc0) shows, this expression is uncommon and, when used in this context, seems to mean the same as the **for** version.

It occurs more often in sentences like this:

> Does it sound **good to you to** go to the beach tomorow?

Comment: if so ( good to you to...
As this NGRAM shows, this expression is uncommon and, when used in this context, seems to mean the same as the for version.)  does "It's good to you to say that" mean "If you say that, it not must but may be good for you " ? Does "It's good for you to say that" mean "If you say that, it must be good for you" ?

Comment: @user22046: I would never use the **to** version in this context:  I am simply reporting that a very small number of people have done.  I can't comment on exactly what the writers intended when they used it:.